# Take decimal numbers only in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a number that I want to take only the decimal part and convert it to an integer with certain precision.

How can I do that in Dart Language or flutter  ?

For example :

**turn this** `247.64646122587197` **into this** `6464`

Drop the float number and take only 4 decimals and convert it to an integer.

Comment: Not specific to dart, but `floor((x % 1) * 10000)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can also do that like this

```
void main() {
    final double abc=247.64646122587197;
    int y = int.tryParse(abc.toString().split('.')[1].substring(0,4));
    print(y);
}
```

output :6464

Comment: Technically works, but it's horribly inefficient. This would also throw an exception for numbers that have less than 4 decimal digits. As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't convert a number to a string unless it's absolutely necessary (and you better have a damn good reason for doing so if you are going to end up just converting it right back).

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work:

```dart
((x % 1) * pow(10, 4)).floor()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
double value = 247.64646122587197;
double decimalValue = value - value.toInt();
print(decimalValue.toStringAsFixed(4))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

`return (247.64646122587197 * 10000).toInt() % 10000;`